# Predict the 2nd Class in Multi-class classification

Tags: python, prediction, predict

Hello I have a multiclass classification model ready and trained on dataset

```
Label    Feat1  Feat2 Feat3 Feat4 
Class1    10     21    12     2
Class2    3      6     7      9
Class3    14     8     8     10
Class4    1      5     5      9
```

I currently can use the predict function in Sckit-Learn to apply the best model for predicting the single class . So I can get column Predicted_Label. How to approach the problem in order to get a list of prediction i.e 2nd or 3rd Best Prediction

```
Test_Data_Set 
Feat1  Feat2   Feat3 Feat4    Predicted_Label   Predicted_Label_2nd_Best_Prediction
 1       3     10     7          Class1           [Class1,Class4]
```

Comment: Which model are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this question: [Understanding predict_proba from MultiOutputClassifier](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/understanding-predict-proba-from-multioutputclassifier)

You need to use `predict_proba()` on your `model` to get probabilities for every class, for every row of your training dataset. In your case you will get an **array of length 4 if you have 4 classes**.

You can then get the second best prediction class for the second largest probability.

[Multiclass MultiOutput Classification example on sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification)

**Note**: Every array of length 4 from `predict_proba()` will add up to 1.